# Single Instance using Mutex in NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to make vb Form a single instance use Mutex. For the developers!

Hi,
I searched in the net how to make a single instance startup form in VB Net not in c# code. Here is my solution:

1. In the project select "Add class..."
2. Rename the new class in "NativeMethods.vb" and put this code:

Add this reference: `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices`

```
    Public Const HWND_BROADCAST As Integer = &HFFFF
        Public Shared ReadOnly WM_SHOWME As Integer = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_SHOWME")
        <DllImport("user32")>
        Public Shared Function PostMessage(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wparam As IntPtr, ByVal lparam As IntPtr) As Boolean
        End Function
        <DllImport("user32")>
        Public Shared Function RegisterWindowMessage(ByVal message As String) As Integer
End Function
```

3. In the project select "Add class..."
4. Rename the new class in "main.vb" and put this code:

Add this reference: `Imports System.Threading`

```
Public Sub Main()
        Dim Mutex As Mutex = New Mutex(True, "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}")
        If Mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, True) Then
            Application.EnableVisualStyles()
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
            Application.Run(New Form1())
            Mutex.ReleaseMutex()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Another instance of this Application is already running.", "Attention Requested", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            NativeMethods.PostMessage(CType(NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST, IntPtr), NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
        End If
    End Sub
```

5. On the Form1 enter the following lines:

```
    Private Const SW_HIDE As Integer = 0
    Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Integer = 1
    Private Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED As Integer = 2
    Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As Integer = 3
    Private Const SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE As Integer = 4
    Private Const SW_RESTORE As Integer = 9
    Private Const SW_SHOWDEFAULT As Integer = 10

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
            Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
            Const SC_RESTORE As Integer = &HF120
            Const SC_MINIMIZE As Integer = &HF020
            If m.Msg = NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME Then
                ShowMe()
            End If
            If m.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND AndAlso CInt(m.WParam) = SC_RESTORE Then
            End If
            If m.Msg = WM_SYSCOMMAND AndAlso CInt(m.WParam) = SC_MINIMIZE Then
            End If
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End Sub

    Private Sub ShowMe()
            If WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            End If
            Show()
            Dim top As Boolean = TopMost
            TopMost = True
            TopMost = top
            'Here you can call your own function. For example if your application uses the command line!
        End Sub
```

6. In the project select "Properties project name..."
7. Remove the check mark on: "Enable Application FrameWork"
8. In the start object select: "Sub Main"
9. Save the project, create the solution and start it

This solution works very well and has been tested on Windows 7/8.1 and 10 32/64 Bit. If anyone finds a better solution, please post it.
Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the WinForms project properties, why not just check the `Make single instance application`?

[image]

Comment: Because it would be too simple ;)

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for - so simple